# What are the height and width types of the Flutter LayoutBuilder class?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I use LayoutBuilder to be responsive while developing applications in Flutter. However, while the width of my emulator is 1600px, when I print maxWitdh to the console in android studio, I encounter a value of 1093.3333333333333. What is the type of height and width values ​​in LayoutBuilder that I am curious about? So the value of 1093.333 is cm, mm, or dm.
(I'm sure it's not px)enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: Should be the amazing "device pixels", the same units you specify everything in.  If the width is less than the hardware, maybe safearea or padding has already removed some of the hardware pixels.

Comment: what is the value of https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/devicePixelRatio.html ?